# Why is inter container communication in Docker the default?

Tags: docker

I’m reading up a little on communication between Docker containers. The `-—icc` flag let all containers communicate to each other. The flag is set to true by default.

As far as I understand this ignores any `EXPOSE` / `-—expose` declarations. They are only enforced when `—-icc` is set to false.

- So why are we exposing ports in the first place?
- Or why isn’t the ICC set to false as as default?

Comment: The `EXPOSE` statements are also useful for (a) automatically publishing ports via `-P` and (b) automatic service discovery when linking containers.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. The `EXPOSE` command is really just metadata. It documents an intent by the developer that the container can be contacted on the given ports. By itself, all the build instruction is doing is adding this metadata to the image.

As yourself and larsks have noted, this information is used by Docker when the `-P` flag and links are invoked.

I assume Docker largely took the stance that as containers run on their own private network, in most cases they will trust each other and it's simplest to just allow all communication.

If you disable ICC, you have to set the `--iptables` flag (which allows docker to edit iptables) and use links to allow containers to communicate. I suspect dynamic editing of iptables was something the Docker engineers wanted to stay away from as long as possible. Also, certain set-ups become impossible due to the limitations of links, for example you can't have bidirectional links.

Comment: _The EXPOSE command is really just metadata_


But from what Iaerned it is used when using --link and enforced with iptables when `--icc=false`. Confusing to me.

Comment: _Setting ICC to false by default would confuse a lot of new users._ 

I'm not sure about that. The docs are all about linking containers, exposing ports and using envs / hostnames. For me it was the other way around: "Why am I able to ping the other container without linking it?"

IMHO it is also a design question: with `--icc=false` you would enforce encapsulation. Which containers are all about.

Comment: @luebken yeah, fair points. I've rewritten my answer slightly. EXPOSE really is just a bit of metadata. I was a bit surprised when I realised how little it did.

Comment: @luebken Just added a point on limitations of links. I suspect that's more the issue; links are a nice feature but don't cover all use cases. And in the past they were more flaky, especially when containers restarted.